# Generate a composite returns for all the shares that I am working on over a dynamic period from a daily price feed in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I want to be able to generate a cumulative returns for all the shares that I am working on over a dynamic period in the current visual context from a daily price feed in Power BI.

I used the below formula to generate the cumulative returns over a dynamic period from a daily price feed ( for three companies ) in Power BI.

```
   ReturnsApple = DIVIDE (
LASTNONBLANKVALUE ( Apple[Date], max([Close])  ),
CALCULATE (
    FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE ( Apple[Date], max([Close]) ),
    OFFSET( -1, ALLSELECTED ( Apple[Date] ), ORDERBY( Apple[Date], ASC ) )
)
```

) - 1

This gives me the image below

[image]

However, I am keen to add an additional column - which I refer to as  Composite returns. The returns calculates
((1+ apple[result])* (1+ amazon[result])* (1+ meta[result]))-1
for all the selected periods as below

[image]

Note: I have the three stocks in separate tables as below

[image]

[image]
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, you are wanting to see the composite return based on one share of each stock, not a weighted portfolio return, right? Is there a particular reason you have each stock in its own table?

Comment: Yes, you should design a proper data model that makes the reports and calculations simple.

Comment: @Luke_0 yes. you are correct (not a weighted portfolio at this stage).  

But I think if I can work out the weighted portfolio return (which is the best solution), it will also work for one share pf each stock.  

No reason particular reason for keeping each stock in a table. When I  tried to combined them, I struggled to create the table I presented, hence I kept them separately.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am a new to Power BI. So any idea will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Try for a single table something like (Month, Company, Amount, Price), joining your existing tables in Power Query.

Comment: @jamesbond, does my answer below solve your question? If so be sure to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need all of your ticker data in the same table.

1. First, add a Ticker column for each individual table in PowerQuery.
   [image]
2. Then appending your individual sources as a new combined source.
   [image]
3. Load the data to the model.
4. Create a table with a list of your tickers. `Tickers = VALUES( data[ticker] )`
5. Create a Calendar table.
   [image]
6. Create your measure:

First we declare a variable for the prior close (`prior`). This takes the value on the last date with non-blank data (`LASTNONBLANKVALUE`) prior to the visual's selected period (`DATESBETWEEN(...,BLANK(),CALCULATE(FIRSTDATE(...),ALLSELECTED(...)))`). This is important if the day immediately prior to the selected period has no data (i.e., markets were not open).

Then we take the last non-blank value on or before the last day in context (like before, important if last day is not a market day) less the prior variable we just calculated (`prior`) and divide that by the prior value to get cumulative change.

```
VAR prior =
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANKVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Date], SUM ( data[Adj Close] ) ),
        DATESBETWEEN (
            'Calendar'[Date],
            BLANK (),
            CALCULATE ( FIRSTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] ), ALLSELECTED ( 'Calendar' ) ) - 1
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
            DATESBETWEEN ( 'Calendar'[Date], BLANK (), LASTDATE ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) ),
            SUM ( data[Adj Close] )
        ) - prior,
        prior
    )
```

---